# How to set persistent cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I am using this PHP code and trying to set cookies as shown below:

```
 setcookie("_GuestID",$userID,time() + (20 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
```

I found that cookies expire just after closing the browser. I want to make it persistent for a long time. How I can do?

Comment: Have you checked, from your browser, whether the cookie was actually set? What is the expiry date?

Comment: you set the expiry time for some point in the future. there's no such thing as "permanent" cookies. just "cookies that won't expire for a long while".

Comment: Cookies are valid for as long as you want (there is a max - google it), or _until the client deletes them_. The client might even refuse them all together. Sessions might be worth a look (although they, too, use a cookie)

Comment: Check out the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38566461/keep-only-specific-sessions-alive-for-several-weeks/38592327#38592327

Answer (score 9):

As has already been noted, check if the cookie is actually being set in your browser (your syntax appears correct).

Cookies will only persist for as long as you have set them. I've always used a year as a round period unless there are specific expiry requirements (which are usually much shorter).

Use the strtotime function to make them easier to read:

```
setcookie( "cookieName1", $value1, strtotime( '+1 year' ) );
setcookie( "cookieName2", $value2, strtotime( '+30 days' ) );
```

There are many examples of how to use them on the [setcookie manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) which is worth taking the time to read.

Answer (score 3):

There is no special way to set persistent cookies. 
Its the same way you set normal cookies.
**Cookies with an expiration date are called persistent.**

Answer (score 3):

Let's understand the cookie bit better...

There are two different types of cookies - session cookies and persistent cookies.

- If a cookie does not contain an expiration date, it is considered a session cookie. Session cookies are stored in memory and never written to disk. When the browser closes, the cookie is permanently lost from this point on.
- If the cookie contains an expiration date, it is considered a
  **persistent cookie**. On the date specified in the expiration, the
  cookie will be removed from the disk

> ```
> $cookie_name = "Name";
> $cookie_value = "Amitesh";
> setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
> ```